# How can I avoid java.net.SocketTimeoutException when debugging my endpoints in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

Sometimes my debugging stops short due to this

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I send a request, my breakpoint is hit, I debug for a while, but then the time-out happens

I tried this property, but it didn't work. The property was parsed and set alright, but it seems it has nothing to do with my timeout

```yaml
server:
  netty:
    connection-timeout: 1d
```

How can I disable or delay it?

Spring Boot 3.2.1, WebFlux, Netty

Comment: You don't give enough information, but a read time-out is a client side error. So changing the server properties won't change anything